# Can StructureMap return a Special Case?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap, null-object-pattern

I want to have StructureMap return a [Special Case](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html) called "None" for a certain instance.

Say I Have this class `MyUser` which is scoped as HttpContext. I want to have a nested, dreived class `None` (ie. `MyUser.None`) which is returtned for the type `MyUser` when there is no `HttpContext` (for example, like in bootstrapping, `Application_Start()` etc).

This would mean that certain calls could check for the Special Case type instead of null (more readable) like

```
if(value is MyUser.None)
  // do special case things
else
  // do normal case things
```

What SM config do I need to achieve this? I have tried the `ConditionallyUse` method without much success. I keep getting `NullReferenceExceptionS` throwing from within SM itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had underlying SM configuration issues.

I am using the `ConditionallyUse` method still however:

```
        For<User>().ConditionallyUse(config =>
            {
                config.If(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<HttpContextBase>().User == null)
                    .ThenIt.Is.Type<User.None>();
                config.TheDefault.Is.Type<User>();
            });
```

I had to be more careful about `NullReferenceExceptionS` from within SM - my underlying cause it seems was a [scoping issue](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/Glossary.htm#section4).. specifically how I was wanting to access a `HttpContext` scoped instance in a test. I'm now using the `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()` config and being more careful by using `TryGetInstance()` where appropiate instead of `GetInstance()`.

Comment: It looks like you used my answer, wrote it up as yours, and accepted it. Shouldn't you accept mine and just add a comment to it that you had missed some NullReferenceExceptions or something?

Comment: No disrespect Josh. I didn't mean to make it appear like that. 
The truth is I was already using the `ConditionallyUse` much like your answer suggested (even tho my question only mentioned _that_ I used it, not how). It's really the explanation of how I solved by underlying issue (after the code snip) which I thought would potentially be more valuable to others. That's why I wrote a new answer. I did actually sit pondering for some time on how to do this on your answer FYI. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: None taken, just trying to understand. Glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work (to test, you can replace the check for HttpContext.Current with something like `DateTime.Now.Millisecond % 2 == 0` to more easily see the different behavior):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IUser>().ConditionallyUse(cond =>
            {
                cond.TheDefault.Is.Type<MyUser>();
                cond.If(ctx =>
                {
                    var hasContext = false;
                    try
                    {
                        hasContext = HttpContext.Current == null;
                    }catch
                    {
                        // HttpContext.Current sometimes throws when there isn't one
                    }
                    return hasContext;
                }).ThenIt.IsThis(new MyUser.None());
            });
        });

        var instance = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUser>();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.GetType());
    }

    public interface IUser{}
    public class MyUser : IUser { public class None : IUser {} }
}
```

Since the `ConditionallyUse()` API is a little strange, you might just want to use the `Use()` overload that takes a `Func<>` and do the conditional check yourself with an `if` statement.

Comment: I'll give those ideas a go. Thanks